# how do I put an image in python

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to put an image in python with pygame, and it is not working.
I get this error:

> line 16, in 
>       carImg = pygame.image.load("")
>   pygame.error: SDL_RWFromFile(): No file or no mode specified`line 16, in module

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)

gamedisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Rockin Racer")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

carImg = pygame.image.load("racecar.png")

def car(x,y):
    gamedisplay.blit(carImg,(x,y))

x = (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.8)




crashed = False

while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    car(x,y)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and take the [tour]. This is a good [mcve]; however, you could make this more minimal by removing most of the actual game logic. I would do it, but, frankly, I have no idea how pygame works.

Comment: First, is your error cut off? Next, can you specify more about your problem, like whether or not it is that the image won't load, file isn't found, or location is not working.

Comment: @Ethanol Nothing is cut off and I have the file in the same directory as the project. It saying that there is not no file found I think it might be a location thing, but don't know how to fix it.

Comment: The code you've posted should work correctly (if you fix the `gamedisplay` / `gameDisplay` typo). 

I can reproduce this error if I pass an empty string to `pygame.image.load`. Passing the incorrect name/path should result in a `pygame.error: Couldn't open racecar.png`. 

Can you load other images correctly or is only this one causing problems? Check out other formats like .jpg as well. And try to run the "aliens.py" and "chimp.py" games in the "pygame/examples" directory to see if pygame works correctly.

Comment: I tried doing the aliens.py and it made an error for loading a gif

Comment: The same error as in the question? Always post the complete traceback. Do you have any other pygame programs with images that can be loaded correctly? Is this the first time you use pygame? Maybe something went wrong during the installation. Which operating system, Python and pygame versions do you use and how did you install pygame? Perhaps a re-installation could help.

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks fine by the code, so I'm assuming that it has something to do with the file location. I'm basing it on your code given(and not the error, because it pretty much says you didn't even give a file). So you say you store your file in the same directory as the project. My solution may vary from system to system and other things, but I believe you have to include `images/`. Try this:

```
carImg = pyvame.image.load("images/racecar.png")
```

If this doesn't work find the location where the images is stored (should be near your code documents) and use that. I hope this helps!

Comment: @John you can accept the answer if it solves your problem.